# Tests order dependency due to constant (final) fields

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

What is the recommended pattern to modify constants for unit tests? This is currently what I've used for some time and today I realized it's flawed.

Assume my class looks like this

```
class Foo {
   private static final int MAX_TIME = Integer.getInteger("myProp", 1000);
   ...
}
```

The fact that I use a VM property is not only to modify it in a unit test. It is because I want it to be immutable from the actual code and I don't want to pollute a constructor with it since it is an implementation detail.

So, in production I want a timeout of 1 second; however that's too long for unit tests so I do this

```
class FooTest {
   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      System.setProperty("myProp", "50");
   }
   @Test
   public void testThatAssumesTimeoutOf50() { ... }
}
```

This worked fine for a long time until today I finally added a `BarTest` like this

```
class BarTest {
   Foo mockFoo = mock(Foo.class); //actually done in a @Before method in the real code
}
```

Now what this created is that my tests fail or pass depending on the order of execution. If `Foo` is tested first, the test that assumes a testing timeout of 50ms passes. But if `Bar` is tested first then this makes `Foo` to be loaded due to the mock so `MAX_TIME` takes the default value of 1000 and then when `BarTest` ends and `FooTest` starts, the test that assumes a testing timeout of 50ms now fails.

Comment: Each class tests should be independent. There are ways to enforce order within a class.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to remove the `final` keyword.  This will let you change the value after class loadtime.

Since you set and get the value across many different classes, and possibly packages, you should probably add a getter and setter.  If you need to change this value across packages, then it will have to be `public`.

```
 class Foo{

   public static int getMaxTime(){
        return MAX_TIME;
   }

   public static  void changeMaxTime(int timeout){
        //validation logic goes here
        this.MAX_TIME = timeout;
   }
```

Then, in your test classes, you should save the old value in the `@BeforeClass` or `@Before` phase, change it to whatever you want, and then restore the old value in the `@AfterClass` or `@After` phase.

Since it looks like you do this across many test classes, it might be best to actually make your own [Test Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules):

```
 public class TimeoutRule extends ExternalResource {

   private final int oldTimeout, newTimeout;

   public TimeoutRule(int timeout){
         this.oldTimeout = Foo.getMaxTime();
         this.newTimeout = timeout;
   }

    @Override
    protected void before() {

    }

   @Override
   protected void after() {
       //restore old timeout
        Foo.setMaxTimeOut(oldTimeout);
}
```

}

Then in your test code:

```
class FooTest {

  @Rule
  public TimeoutRule timeoutRule = new TimeoutRule(50);

  @Test
  public void testThatAssumesTimeoutOf50() { ... }
```

}

That code will reset the timeout to 50 ms and then restore it to the original value after every test.  If you wanted to only do it once per test class, use `@ClassRule` instead (and make the field `static`)